# XCodeProj, .App files on DropBox

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, dropbox

When I drop a .XCodeProj or .App file in DropBox (and there I am assuming, other packages)the files in the package seems to be randomly not copied--sometimes none of them are copied, sometimes some of them, never all of them.

This happens even when I zip the file, copy it to dropbox and unzip it there.

How could DropBox have this grave an error this far along in it's existence? Lost a whole day of work finding this out. Disastrous.

In particular the project.pbxproj file was NEVER successfully copied into dropbox, or at least never made it to any of my other drives that were synced with the first.

Does anyone know if there is a fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to delete previous version of the file you want to upload to Dropbox (.XCodeProj, .app or .zip) with the web interface and then try upload it again. You can do this in 3 easy steps:

> 1. Log in to Dropbox
> 2. Click the "Show Deleted Files" button
> 3. Find and delete the old version of the file you want to upload (The grey one)

Also: Dropbox doesn't upload the whole file everytime you upload a newer version of it, infact it only uploads the newer parts (But I'm not 100% sure about this).

I hope my answer can help you :-)

Comment: Thanks, not an answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**.app** is essentially a directory, so Dropbox will see it as one and uploads each individual file in there.

You need to zip your project directory then sync to dropbox; same would go for the **.app**.

Comment: It isn't essentially a directory, it IS a directory ;-) And the problem is that DropBox is not uploading every file in that directory, specifically it seems not to see project.pbxproj in .xcodeproj files. This is a real problem!